# Page reload on modal popup submit

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I am not able to reload the page using vuejs and bootstrap modal popup in laravel. 
i have a form inside the modal popup:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="userAddModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" method="POST" @submit="AddNewUser">
        ...
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is my vuejs code:

```js
methods: {
        fetchUser: function () {
            this.$http.get('../api/users', function (data) {
                this.$set('users', data)
            });
        },
 AddNewUser: function () {
            //e.preventDefault();
            var user = this.newUser;
            this.newUser = {fname: '', mname: '', lname: '', cid: '', email: '', password: '', utype: ''};
            console.log(this.newUser);
            this.$http.post('../api/users', user);
            $('#userAddModal').modal('hide');
            this.fetchUser()
}
```

Everytime i submit, the user gets add but when the page refreshes, i get error like:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 8873:

if i put `@submit.prevent` in the form, the page doesn't get refreshed with `this.fetchUser()` method inside `AddnewUser` function. please help me out...thanks

Comment: try to remove the `method="POST"` in your form declaration

Comment: Show us your routing. And do not use: `'../api/users'` - you can: `'/api/users'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely going to need to prevent the form from being submitted with `@submit.prevent` as you suggest. Otherwise the browser will submit the form itself.

There are a few small errors in your code. First, the vue-resource methods ($http.get and $http.post) return promises, so use `.then` instead of passing in callbacks. Secondly, you're calling `fetchUser` before your post request has gone through. Finally, the response data is in `response.data`, not passed in directly as a parameter to your callback as you did.

The following code should work:

```
methods: {
  fetchUser: function () {
    this.$http.get('/api/users').then(function (response) {
      this.$set('users', response.data);
    });
  },
  AddNewUser: function () {
    var user = this.newUser;
    this.newUser = {fname: '', mname: '', lname: '', cid: '', email: '', password: '', utype: ''};
    console.log(this.newUser);

    this.$http.post('/api/users', user).then(function () {
      this.fetchUser();
    });

    $('#userAddModal').modal('hide');
  }
```